# Querying a database - Webservice only access

Tags: sql, xml, web-services

We are attempting to run some queries over a database (27,000 records) to ask questions such as :

- Show an example of a particular table / section being used
- Show all examples which meet this criteria
- Some all examples of a particular field

We only have XML access via Webservices to the data. The webservices provide some filtering functions but they are very basic and geared around a sort of faceted search.

I can think of three major ways to achieve this (of course there are many more - just the ones I'm considering) :

1. Write a perl/python script to pull all data and stick it somewhere
2. Use some kind of an ETL tool to import all the data and map it to a database
3. Write some kind of a script that can search the data "live" using the webservices available

I think 3. is out - the webservices just don't provide enough functionality.

Is there any automated awesome tools that can convert XML to SQL in a form that is vaguely usable and searchable? How would you go about solving this problem?

Prefer a Linux/open-source environment solution and ideally some way to achieve this fast and free rather than with an expensive tool.

Comment: 27000 records is not a large database.

Comment: Actually, 27000 records is tiny.  27,000,000 records would be large.

Comment: Fixed - removed the word "large". Any idea how you would typically answer this question? Any cool tools built around solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

27k rows isn't really a large database IMO - so unless the rows are excessively large (e.g. unless each row is a deep entity graph), pulling all rows from the web service into memory and caching them there seems a perfectly good approach - you might also look at re-storing the data in SQL (e.g. as an XML field) or in a NoSQL database like [MongoDb](http://www.mongodb.org/) (Although you should reserialize the data back into JSON/BSON to get the most out of Mongo).

You will need to implement a mechanism to detect changes on the live underlying data in order to refresh your cached data.

When bulk-pulling data from the source webservices, because xml is such a verbose protocol over the wire, so you may need to break up the data from the web services into chunks to avoid timeouts or other issues.

*Re : Tools for querying Xml*
[xQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XQuery) will allow you to perform arbitrary searches on xml data, and in .Net you have tools like Linq2Xml. Also, if you can load all the data into a single Xml stream / document, you will be able to use Xpath to query it.

Comment: Awesome answer - thanks very much. I think it will be too large to store in memory as each record would be more than 1mb in XML - although I will need to do some tests to check. What open-source database would be best for storing XML? Postgres has native XML support, MongoDB seems to support this through 28msec but I think that is a paid service.